# Install ADB interface driver for android

Tags: android, device-driver

I tried to install through Device Manager. After I connected the phone to my laptop, i got link as 'Celkon incorporated GSM handset' in 'Other devices' portion of Device manager. I right clicked and clicked 'uddate driver' and 'install from specified location' and located the 'inf' file (usb2ser_2kXP.inf), but the messsage is ' cannot install this hardware, and 'the wizard cannot find the necessary software'..

So, how i have to edit the 'inf' file ?

Answer (score 5):

> Right click on My Computer-->then go to manage--> then right click on
> it and select update device driver--> select your device in other
> device in Device manager-->

[image: Step 1]

> Choose to manually search the device instead of automatically doing
> it.

[image: Step 2]

> Choose to show all the devices.

[image: Step 3]

> To manually locate the device driver for ADB Interface, click on Have
> Disk.

[image: Step 4]

> Click on 'Browse'

[image]

> go to sdk-->extra-->google-->usb driver-->then click on
> android_winusb.inf-->click open

```
Check your SDK Manager whether your 'Google USB driver' is installed or not.
Make sure that your environment variables are set up:

ANDROID_HOME : %LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk

PATH: ;%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk\tools
```

[image]

> Android ADB Interface will be recognized.

[image: Step 7]

Check to see that the error is removed and your ADB device interface should be working now.

Answer (score 2):

http://adbdriver.com/upload/adbdriver.zip

- Download adb driver installer and open it
- Connect your phone to PC(make sure USB Debugging is enabled)
- Phone will be listed with driver status whether it is installed or not
- Just click on install, allow to install the driver if any popup asks and wait for a while
- After installing the driver, reconnect you phone to PC

Note: This driver may work in any of the Android devices.

Comment: Glad to know it helps you,

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue before but I solved it easily by just following these steps:

```
*connect your android phone in a debugging mode
```

(to enable debugging mode, go to **settings**, scroll down **About Phone**, scroll down **tap seven times Build Number** and it will automatically enable developer option, turn on developer options and check USB debugging)

download [Universal ADB Driver Installer](http://adbdriver.com/)

*choose Adb Driver Installer (Universal)

```
*install it 
*it will automatically detect your android device(any kind of brand)
```

*chose the device and install

Answer (score 0):

```
STEP A:
Get the MTK6573 ADB driver from
h*t*t*p://chinamobiles.org/downloads/zap/MT6573ADBdrivers.zip
And extract it to a folder. The MTK6573 ADB interface driver works fine on MTK6575 based devices.

STEP B:
Get the VENDOR and DEVICE Ids of your Celkon A97 phone.
To get it,
Connect the phone to your PC. Open Device Manager. Look for Celkon incorporated GSM handset under Other Devices
Open 'Celkon incorporated GSM handset' -->Properties-->Details tab.
Under property dropdown menu, Select Hardware IDs
and note the 4 digit VID_XXXX and PID_YYYY values. These are the phones Hardware iDs.

STEP C:
Open the file android_winusb.inf using your favourite text editor.
Add three lines after this line.

[Manufacturer]
%ProviderName% = Google, NTx86, NTamd64

The three lines are
; CELKON A97
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_XXXX&PID_YYYY&MI_01
;

Replace XXXX, YYYY with Vendor and Device IDs of your phone.
Save the file.


STEP D:
Once you update these values, update the driver from the device manager by pointing to the folder of android_winusb.inf.
Now you should see a ADB interface device in the device manager.
```