# Android studio doesn't show my LG G5 under connected devices

Tags: android, android-studio, usb

I'm new to android and I'm trying to run my app on my G5 (not a virtual emulator) but cant somehow make my android studio recognize my phone.

I've already installed Google USB Driver, tried to switch the settings on my phone to PTP and reinstalled my phone in the device manager.

Can someone help me with this issue?

that's what I keep seeing:

[image]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html

Comment: try to reinstall the usb drivers like this...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559734/install-adb-interface-driver-for-android/35968244#35968244

Comment: I followed the instructions but after connecting my device the dialog asking whether to accept an RSA key never poped

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resolved by:
SETTINGS -> ABOUT THE DEVICE -> SOFTWARE INFO -> PRESS **7** TIMES ON BUILD NUMBER
you'll get "You are a developer now" notification and have new "developer options" in your settings menu, tap on it and enable developer options.

Comment: Note that the entry "USB-Debugging" may be grayed out while the device is connected to a PC via USB. Remove the USB cable and the "USB Debugging" entry will "come to life" and can be switched-on.

Answer (score 10):

My LG G5 needs to set the "Use USB connection for" on "Photo transfer".

When you connect your device on the PC, you can see it in notifications

Comment: Mine was in File transfer by default,
when i change to 'Photo transfer' then the android studio showed up my device

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already you need to put your phone in developer mode and select "allow usb debugging" and if you're using Linux you may need to change the udev rules to allow android studio to interact with your phone. Here's the page explaining how to do that.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html

Answer (score 0):

Install **PdaNEt+** in your computer
http://pdanet.co/

Enable USB Debugging of your device through Developers Mode
http://www.syncios.com/android/how-to-debug-lg-g5.html

And then Connect your device.
If you found any issue ,feel free to ask me

Answer (score -1):

USB PC connection is set to Media device (MTP) (Wireless or Bluetooth). ... Enter in developer mode and you'll find this [USB Debugging](http://gsmorigin.com/get-developer-options-lg-g5-lg-g6/) option.