# device not detected on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to run my android project on android studio 1.2. I have started the developer options on my phone and the USB debugging but my android device is still not detected on the running devices. I have tried the invalidate  cache/restart but still doesn't work, kindly help.

Comment: Does your device connect to the computer at all, for example when you go to My Computer your device should show up. If it shows up you might need to go to android settings and developer options enable USB debugging.

Comment: Android Studio 1.2 is over a year old... Try upgrading

Comment: which device you have and first install the particular android device installer in your pc system.

Comment: Make sure adb driver is installed

Comment: @Chad Yes the device is detected on the computer. I am using an Infinix hot5 running on android 7

Comment: @HarshitTrivedi   I am using an Infinix hot5 running on android 7

Comment: And USB debugging is turned on?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559734/install-adb-interface-driver-for-android/35968244#35968244

Comment: @Chad yes the USB debugging is on

Comment: You have to enable the **USB debugging** option in the Developer Options of your phone. It is the first option under the **Debugging** section. Android Studio recognized my phone after I enabled this option. Make sure to accept all the permission requests that pop up on the phone's screen. Checkout my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58258251/10259491

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely reason you're not see is one of these:

1) The cable is bad, in that case replace it. Try another cable.

2) The drivers aren't installed on your computer. Download them here: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html

3) Another program (i.e. Samsung Kies) is causing problems, close it.

4) The device is port is faulty, in that case you'll need to replace it

5) The computer usb port is faulty.

6) If its intermittent, try to connect to your phone w/ adb wifi

7) If your phone is rooted you won't need to connect, use wifi adb by default. Use this app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=en

Hope it helps

Answer (score 10):

In my case, enabling `USB Debugging` in `Developer Options` solved the problem. Make sure to grant required permissions upon reconnecting the phone.

**Enabling Developer Options**

`Phone settings >> About Phone >> Software Information >> tap Build Number repeatedly.`

**Update:**

Sometimes, the phone is not detected even with `USB Debugging` on. In this case, tap on `Revoke USB debugging authorizations` in `Developer options`. Grant the required permissions on reconnecting the phone.

If it's still not being detected, then toggle `USB debugging` off and on then grant permissions upon phone reconnection.

Comment: Remembering to enable developer options is one thing - remembering to turn on "enable USB debugging" is another. Don't be like me.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no specific solution to this problem. There is one or more than one reason behind this problem. Maybe your cable is broken or USB port is faulty etc. At first, make sure that all of your hardware is working properly

Now connect your phone to PC's USB port via the charging/data cable. If it displays Charging, Photo or File transfer, select the file transfer option.

[image]

Now go to the Developer Options and enabled the Developer mode. `(Different mobile manufacturer has different settings, try to find where is your's developer settings located. In my case, it is Settings --> Additional Settings --> Developer Option)`

After enabling the Developer Option, enable the `USB Debugging (*most important)`. If you find `Verify Apps Over USB` option or something similar, enable that option also.

[image]

Now wait for a few seconds, Your phone will be detected by the Android Studio

[image]

Comment: not working i have oppo a37

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem guys, the adb drivers were not installed, so I downloaded the installer, followed the precise steps on installing my device's drivers and it now works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

In my case I installed Platform tools and placed in the Sdk path and I installed all Sdk related to the version of My mobile then it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Update Android Studio. Current version is [2.3.3](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) Yours is 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

1. Check if adb server is able to detect your device, by typing `adb devices` in project terminal.
2. If it is able to list the device, then Go to mobile`s settings -> developer options -> allow USB debugging. (If it is already allowed, then deselect it and select it again). This simple step worked for me, after trying tons of things.
3. If the `adb devices` command is not able to list the device, then , in android studio -> "Device List Drop Down" -> "Troubleshoot Device Connections" -> Follow the steps. By this step, device should be able to get detected by adb, then repeat step 1 & 2 in order.

Comment: adb not recognized